# Negative top margin in firefox and IE when using @font-face

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I've been developing a website in Google Chrome and finally decided to see what it looked like in IE and Firefox. To my astonishment, Firefox and Internet Explorer both had the same issue compared to chrome. When using @font-face to import a font Google Chrome displays things the way I want it to, but Firefox and Internet Explorer both show the font with an imaginary "negative top margin". I attached some screenshots as it is a bit hard to explain.

Google Chrome

[image: Google Chrome]

Firefox

[image: Firefox]

Internet Explorer

[Internet Explorer http://img846.imageshack.us/img846/3021/a78c216586e54bc2b05d2a8.png](http://img846.imageshack.us/img846/3021/a78c216586e54bc2b05d2a8.png)

Google Chrome

[image: Google Chrome]

Firefox

[image: Firefox]

Internet Explorer

[image: Internet Explorer]

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? I haven't implemented browser-fix so all the CSS for the navigation bar is:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#main">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#news">NEWS</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#events">EVENTS</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#music">MUSIC</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#study">STUDY</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#gallery">GALLERY</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#shop">SHOP</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
#nav a {
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 105px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: bebas;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555555;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

Markup for the events list is:

```
<div class="entry">
    <div class="date">
        <div class="day">15</div>
        <div class="month">Nov</div>
    </div>      
    <div class="location">
        <div class="city">Melbourne</div>
        <div class="club">St Judes Anglican Church</div>
    </div>  
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

```
#events .entry{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: bebas;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #555555;
    word-spacing: 4px;
    border-top: 2px solid #4A3948;
}
.city{
    font-size: 40px;
}

.location{
    padding-left:10px;
}
.day{
    font-size: 65px;
    line-height: 55px;
}
.date{
    text-align: center;
    width: 95px;
    border-right: 4px solid;
}
.club{
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 31px;
}
```

Does anyone have any information on this issue?

Comment: Where's the markup...you've only put in the css.

Comment: @AdityaSaxena I added markup. The list items have no styling.

Comment: Chances are the font's metrics have a bug and IE/Firefox are using the metric that's wrong but Google is not using it because it's relying on other parts of the font metrics instead...  Have you looked at the font's metrics in a decent font editor?

Comment: @BorisZbarsky Nup, but as it isn't just a single font that it happens with, I doubt its that. I'll check tho.

Comment: OK.  Well, it's hard to say anything else without seeing the actual markup involved.  Given your styling above, the HOME and NEWS should end up stacked vertically, but they're next to each other in your screenshots, so clearly there are more relevant styles here.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky Oh sorry, right... the `li` have `float: left;` applied to them -.-

Comment: OK.  What else is relevant?  Seriously, just posting a link to a page showing the behavior would be most helpful.....

Comment: It's locally hosted, but I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the font's metrics as Boris Zbarsky suggested in the comments. I downloaded a fresh copy of the typekit from a specialised @font-face website and its working now!

Answer (score 0):

Here "#nav a" instead of height try to remove height and use padding:20px 25px;

Comment: Does nothing but make the buttons height extremely large

Answer (score 0):

I have mentioned example padding according to your font-size you can add use padding....

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you could introduce LINE-HEIGHT?

Comment: They all have line-height already as a hack for vertical aligning them center.